Facing CORS Error When Fetching Xero Node/Python SDK APIs in React App
I am encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error while attempting to fetch data from the Xero node SDK APIs within my React application. Despite configuring the necessary headers and permissions on both the client and server sides, the CORS policy persists, preventing successful communication between the frontend React app and the Xero APIs.
React code:
const handleConnection = async() => {
     await fetch("http://localhost:5000/connect").then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
     console.log("success");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
      // Handle error, e.g., display an error message to the user
    });
};

Node Code:
app.get("/connect", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const consentUrl = await xero.buildConsentUrl();
    res.redirect(consentUrl);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("Sorry, something went wrong");
  }
});

I have implemented using this document - (https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node)
Error Screenshot:
CORS Error
I am seeking guidance on how to effectively resolve the CORS error when fetching data from the Xero node SDK APIs within my React application. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

CORS is a browser thing, it’s not something that exists in the server. The screenshot you’ve posted is of an error in a browser console trying to fetch directly from the Xero API, but this post (and the node SDK) makes it look like your app should be sending a request to your local server that then sends a request to Xero, your app should not send a request directly from the frontend. What is your actual setup? I’m confused

Oh, I think I may understand now. The consent URL you return from your local server, you shouldn’t be making an XHR to request from that URL, you need to send your user directly to it - think window.location = - with the correct redirect uri, and Xero will send your user back to a redirect uri with a token (or means to obtain them).

"CORS is a browser thing, it’s not something that exists in the server". It is absolutely something that exists in a server because the server is what needs to dictate what origins it allows to access it and provide the necessary headers.

Touché @possum, poor phrasing. Meant to say “CIRS errors” (not sure if that would’ve been better). Either way, it looks like the OP is making an XHR/fetch request to an endpoint they should be redirecting the user to instead. Either that or they’re trying to use the access token to access the connections endpoint from the FE directly, instead of doing it on the server.

You should be making your call to /connections (or updateTenants) on your server, not on the front end.
Check the usage examples: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node?tab=readme-ov-file#usage-examples
It looks like you are experiencing a CORS error in your browser. The /connections endpoint isn't meant to be called by the front end of a web application via an XHR or fetch, it is meant to be called by your node server where you have securely stored your client credentials (clientId and clientSecret) - as these cannot be securely stored ion the front end.

Then how should I get details of tenants or users in frontend

@Utkarsh by making a call to your own API which then calls the Xero API on your own server. Ideally you’d also store “last known” states of your users Xero connections in your own DB instead of making a call to Xero every single time

by making a call to own API which then calls the Xero API, it also responds to CORS error.
